# ReferenceError: time is not defined

Tags: javascript

Variable times seems undefined, but as a newbie to js, can't understand whats the prob. Tried to declare var time globally then incremented inside condition but not working.

```js
var j1 = 0;
var j2 = 0;
var j3 = 4;

var time;

if((j1||j2||j3)>=3){
    
    
   time+5000;

    while(time === 30000){
        if(j1>=3){
            alert("Junction 1 is flooded");
        }else if(j2>=3){
            alert("Junction 2 is flooded");
        }else if(j3>=3){
            alert("Junction 3 is flooded");
        }else if ((j1&&j2)>=3){
            alert("Junction 1 & 2 are flooded");
        }else if ((j1&&j3)>=3){
            alert("Junction 1 & 3 are flooded");
        }else if ((j2&&j3)>=3){
            alert("Junction 2 & 3 are flooded");
        }else if ((j1&&j3)>=3){
            alert("Junction 1 & 3 are flooded");
        }else if ((j1&&j3&&j2)>=3){
            alert("All 3 junctions are flooded");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `times` is `undefined` while `time` is declared but not defined too. `time + 5000;` isn't helpful, did you mean `time += 5000;`?

Comment: `if((j1||j2||j3) >= 3)` is a non sense, you can't factorise conditions such way.

Comment: `while (time === 30000)` this part will always be false and the loop never executed.

Comment: the value of  j1,j2,j3 gets changed every 10 seconds with updated data and value of time is updated as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time+5000;` doesn't do anything for you because `time` is `undefined` because all you did was declare, but not initialize it with:

```
var time; // Declared but not initialized === undefined
```

and you can't do math with `undefined`.

Additionally, you aren't capturing the result of the math operation.

**Make it:**

```
var time = 0; // Declared and initialized ;)
```

**and then:**

```
time = time + 5000; // Assign result of expression back to variable
```

**Next, your `if` conditions are incorrect.** Tests for multiple values must be done individually, so this:

```
if((j1||j2||j3)>=3){
```

needs to become this:

```
if(j1 >= 3 || j2 >= 3 || j3 >=3){
```

Lastly, the way your code is now, `time` will only ever be incremented once, to a value of `5000`, so you will never enter into your `while` loop. Then, even if do enter your loop, you don't modify the value of `time` within it, so the loop will never end.  You need to set up some kind of condition to check to determine if the loop should continue. It should be something like:

```
while(time < 50000){
  if(time === 30000){
    if(j1 >= 3){
        alert("Junction 1 is flooded");
    }else if(j2 >= 3){
        alert("Junction 2 is flooded");
    }else if(j3 >= 3){
        alert("Junction 3 is flooded");
    }else if (j1 >= 3 && j2 >=3){
        alert("Junction 1 & 2 are flooded");
    }else if (j1 >= 3 && j3 >= 3){
        alert("Junction 1 & 3 are flooded");
    }else if (j2 >= 3 && j3 >=3){
        alert("Junction 2 & 3 are flooded");
    }else if (j1 >= 3 && j3>=3){
        alert("Junction 1 & 3 are flooded");
    }else if (j1 >=3 && j3 >=3 &&j2 >=3){
        alert("All 3 junctions are flooded");
    }
  }

  time = time + 5000;  // <-- You need to create a situation where the loop can end! 
}
```

So, putting it all together:

```js
var j1 = 0;
var j2 = 0;
var j3 = 4;

var time = 0;

if(j1 >= 3 || j2 >= 3 || j3 >=3){

  while(time < 50000){
      // Check what time is with an "if"
      if(time === 30000){
        if(j1 >= 3){
            alert("Junction 1 is flooded");
        }else if(j2 >= 3){
            alert("Junction 2 is flooded");
        }else if(j3 >= 3){
            alert("Junction 3 is flooded");
        }else if (j1 >= 3 && j2 >=3){
            alert("Junction 1 & 2 are flooded");
        }else if (j1 >= 3 && j3 >= 3){
            alert("Junction 1 & 3 are flooded");
        }else if (j2 >= 3 && j3 >=3){
            alert("Junction 2 & 3 are flooded");
        }else if (j1 >= 3 && j3>=3){
            alert("Junction 1 & 3 are flooded");
        }else if (j1 >=3 && j3 >=3 &&j2 >=3){
            alert("All 3 junctions are flooded");
        }
      }

      time = time + 5000;  // <-- You need to create a situation where the loop can end! 
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(time === 30000)` will always be false, and if it's true, it will result an infinite loop

Comment: @Cid I didn't initially intend to fix every error in the code as the question didn't ask about those things. But, I have at this point.

Answer (score 0):

use `time+=5000;` instead `time+5000;`

Answer (score 0):

You should set time equal to 0 and use += to increment it.

```
var time=0;

if(j1>=3||j2>=3||j3>=3){


   time+=5000;
```

Just writing `var time;` is the same as `var time = undefined` and you can not perform mathematical operations on undefined. You need to initialize the variable.

To increment the time variable, you need to set it to 5000 plus itself or `time = time + 5000` or as shorthand, `time += 5000`.